# Understanding what java code prints

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Hi guys I am fairly new to this and have a question about this code. I am unsure about how the output is what it is so if someone could explain it to a beginner I'd be grateful! This is the code:

```
public class NewClass{

    public static int[] first(int[] a) { // Array {1,2,3} is passed as an argument
        int[] b = new int[a.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
        return b;
    }

    public static void second(int[] a) { // Use more descriptive names for you methods. If its aim is to reverse the array than call it reverseArray or something alike.
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) { // a.length = 3, a.length/2 = 1; So this loop will run only once
            int temp = a[i]; // temp = 4
            a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i]; // a[0] = a[3 - 1 - 0] (a[2]) equals a[0] = 6
            a[a.length - 1 - i] = temp; // a[2] = temp equals a[2] = 4
        } // Array has become {6,5,4} (So it's been reversed.)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; // Array of two elements, both elements refering to an other array with three elements
        System.out.println(matrix.length);  // This will print 2. It is a two dimensional array. 
        first(matrix[0]);   // Calling the first method and passing the {1,2,3} array as argument. It does stuff to a copy of the array (int[] b), but the returned value is never used. Array {1,2,3} is untouched.
        second(matrix[1]); // Same as with the first method
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) // You should use { }. It will make the code easier to read. Only line 25 is executed inside this nested loop
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]); // This will run 6 times (2 (outer loop) x 3 (nested loop)). It will print matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2], matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2]. Respectively 123 (next line) 456
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs 2, then 1,2,3 and finally 6,5,4.

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to step through the code in a debugger and observe the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first function you are creating a new array. This array is returned however the value is never copied into the original. Therefore when printing the matrix the first loop will stay as 1, 2, 3. If you want this to change switch the line:

```
first(matrix[0]);
```

To:

```
matrix[0] = first(matrix[0]);
```

The second function takes the original array and loops once (since a.length is 3 and 3 / 2 = 1). During this loop it converts a[0] to a[a.length - 1 - i] or a[3 - 1 - 0]. It then switches a[a.length - 1 - i] or a[2] to temp which is a[0]. This will switch the first and last element in the array which are 6 and 4.

Comment: thank you. I completely missed the 'new' keyword in the first function

Comment: Glad to help. Also if you want a bit of an easier way to print the array try the Arrays.toString() method. In this case replace the inner for loop with Arrays.toString(matrix[i])

Answer (score 0):

At first, your code is quite messy. Try to use the proper indentation (four spaces for each block). It makes the code easier to read (and you might have figured out the answer yourself).

```
public class NewClass{

    public static int[] first(int[] a) { // Array {1,2,3} is passed as an argument
        int[] b = new int[a.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
        return b;
    }

    public static void second(int[] a) { // Use more descriptive names for you methods. If its aim is to reverse the array than call it reverseArray or something alike.
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) { // a.length = 3, a.length/2 = 1; So this loop will run only once
            int temp = a[i]; // temp = 4
            a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i]; // a[0] = a[3 - 1 - 0] (a[2]) equals a[0] = 6
            a[a.length - 1 - i] = temp; // a[2] = temp equals a[2] = 4
        } // Array has become {6,5,4} (So it's been reversed.)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; // Array of two elements, both elements refering to an other array with three elements
        System.out.println(matrix.length);  // This will print 2. It is a two dimensional array. 
        first(matrix[0]);   // Calling the first method and passing the {1,2,3} array as argument. It does stuff to a copy of the array (int[] b), but the returned value is never used. Array {1,2,3} is untouched.
        second(matrix[1]); // Same as with the first method
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) // You should use { }. It will make the code easier to read. Only line 25 is executed inside this nested loop
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]); // This will run 6 times (2 (outer loop) x 3 (nested loop)). It will print matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2], matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2]. Respectively 123 (next line) 456
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs 2, then 1,2,3 and finally 6,5,4.